# Recursively print pyramid of numbers

Tags: python, recursion

I have to print a pyramid of numbers with this rule:

odd index: 1 to index,
even index: index to 1:

```
1
21
123
4321
12345
654321
1234567
87654321
123456789
```

I wrote this code:

```
def printFigure(rows):
    if rows > 0:
        if rows%2 == 0:
            printFigure(rows-1)
            while(rows>0):
                print(str(rows)[::-1], end = '')
                rows -= 1
            print('')

        if rows%2 == 1:
            printFigure(rows-1)
            while (rows>0):
                print(str(rows),end = '')
                rows -= 1
            print('')
```

but the output is:

```
1
21
321,
4321
54321
654321
7654321
87654321
987654321
```

I'm a beginner with recursion, I'll be glad for your explanations too.
thanks.

Comment: Do you need to use recursion?

Comment: `print('\n'.join([''.join(map(str, range(1, n+1)[::(-1)**(n%2)])) for n in range(1, 10)]))`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis `(1,-1)[n%2]` :D

Comment: @MateenUlhaq It is the same number of bytes though, right? But nice!

Comment: @Ev.Kounis If we're golfing, I think this is the shortest I can get it to: `print('\n'.join('123456789'[:n][::(-1,1)[n%2]]for n in range(1,10)))`

Comment: @MateenUlhaq `n%2*2-1` and in python2 you can skip parenthesis. And range(9): `print'\n'.join('123456789'[:n+1][::1-n%2*2]for n in range(9))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two major problems with your current code.  First, the check on whether the `rows` is even or odd should be happening *after* the recursive call to `printFigure`.  The reason for this is that it is after backing out from the recursive call that you want to decide to print the line in order or backwards.

The second problem was with the logic in the `else` printing condition.  You need to print starting at 1, up to the number of rows.  I used a dummy variable to achieve this, though there are probably a few other ways of doing it.

```
def printFigure(rows):
    if rows > 0:
        printFigure(rows-1)
        if rows%2 == 0:
            while(rows>0):
                print(str(rows)[::-1], end='')
                rows -= 1
            print('')
        else:
            i = 1
            while (i <= rows):
                print(str(i), end='')
                i += 1
            print('')

printFigure(9)

1
21
123
4321
12345
654321
1234567
87654321
123456789
```

Comment: @BenjaminYakobi if the answer help you you should accept it, for other who will search the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

if you don't need to use recursivion, other simple solution is:

```
def printFigure(rows): 
    for x in range(rows): 
        items = [str(i) for i in range(1, x + 1)] 
        if x % 2 == 0: 
            items = items[::-1] 
        print(''.join(items))
```

Comment: extremley short and much more simple than my code for sure.

Comment: glad you liked it )

Answer (score 2):

You could use an inner function that prints from bottom to top, and the call this function from an outer function, for instance:

```
def print_rows(n, limit):
    if n < limit:
        numbers = range(1, n + 1) if n % 2 == 1 else reversed(range(1, n + 1))
        print(''.join(map(str, numbers)))
        print_rows(n + 1, limit)


def print_pyramid_recursive(n):
    if n > 0:
        print_rows(1, n)


print_pyramid_recursive(10)
```

**Output**

```
1
21
123
4321
12345
654321
1234567
87654321
123456789
```

In this case the inner function is `print_rows` and the outer function is `print_pyramid_recursive`. Note, that this problem has a very simple non-recursive solution, for example:

```
def print_pyramid(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        numbers = range(1, i + 1) if i % 2 == 1 else reversed(range(1, i + 1))
        print(''.join(map(str, numbers)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest loop version:

```
is_reversed = False
for i in range(1, 10):
    step = -1 if is_reversed else 1
    print(''.join(map(str, range(1, i + 1)))[::step])
    is_reversed = not is_reversed
```

This regenerates a string every iteration. We can also store the value of the previous result and build on that:

```
s = ''
is_reversed = False
for i in range(1, 10):
    s += str(i)
    step = -1 if is_reversed else 1
    print(s[::step])
    is_reversed = not is_reversed
```

And of course, this can easily (and pointlessly) be converted to a tail-recursive function by just passing along the stack:

```
def f(s, i, max_i, is_reversed):
    if i == max_i:
        return
    s += str(i)
    step = -1 if is_reversed else 1
    print(s[::step])
    is_reversed = not is_reversed
    i += 1
    f(s, i, max_i, is_reversed)

f('', 1, 10, False)
```

The results for each of these increasingly weird looking pieces of code:

```
1
21
123
4321
12345
654321
1234567
87654321
123456789
```

Comment: thanks man!
Its a homework and my function can get only one parameter,
but I'll write this solution for my self learning

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple recursion:

```
def print_pyramid(_count = 1):
  if _count < 10:
    print((lambda x:x[::-1] if not _count%2 else x)(''.join(map(str, range(1, _count+1)))))
    print_pyramid(_count+1)


print_pyramid()
```

Output:

```
1
21
123
4321
12345
654321
1234567
87654321
123456789
```